# docker container naming pattern

Tags: docker, docker-container

How do i change the docker container naming pattern ??

These are some of the names that it has generated.
[image]

after searching the pattern and googling i found out that the 1st word is always a adjective and the 2nd word is a name of persons who have achieved a lot in their professional career(mostly scientists and mathematicians). where does docker take the name from?? can i give it a pattern ??

Comment: You can also set a name when you start a container.

Comment: I want it auto generated but with a pattern I can recognize and utilize it's names to do other stuff.

Comment: Then DaknOb's answer is what you are looking for. You'll need to modify the source-code and recompile. Note that you'll need to do this at each version if you want to stay up-to-date. I do insist that you should name the container when started: `docker run --name auto-generated-name docker-image`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is inside `docker`'s source code. You can change this pattern by downloading the source code and then recompiling it. It is essentially two lists with adjectives and names. [This](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/630a5a23c73276faefaedd0b639ce1525c2bdc24/pkg/namesgenerator/names-generator.go) is the file.